# Set of Partitions with π

Tags: relations, order-theory

Let $\Pi(M)$ be the set of partitions of the set $M$. On $\Pi(M)$ we define the relation $\leq$ like so. For $\pi, \pi' \in \Pi(M)$ we say $\pi \leq \pi'$ applies when for all $A \in \pi$ and $B\in\pi'$ with $A \subseteq B$.

(i)  Show:$\leq$ is a partially set of orders on $\Pi(M)$. (already solved this one)

(ii)  Determine the Set $M$, so that $\leq$ is a total set of orders. (I think i solved this one but im not quite sure) I got that $A,B\in\pi$.

(iii)  Show:  Is $M=\{1,...,n\}$, are $\pi_1,...,\pi_r \in\Pi(M)$ different in pairs and when $\pi_1\leq\pi_2\leq···\leq\pi_r$ applies, then $r \leq n$.

i really dont know how i should do (iii)

Comment: Hint, suppose let $1\leq i<r$ and suppose that $\pi_{i}$ has $k$ elements. Then $\pi_{i+1}$ has the same $k$ elements as $\pi_{i}\leq \pi_{i+1}$. Furthermore since $\pi_{i}\neq\pi_{i+1}$ there is some $j\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $j\in\pi_{i+1}$ and $j\not\in\pi_{i}$. So $\pi_{i+1}$ has at least $k+1$ elements.

Comment: Isn't rather $\pi\le\pi'$ if for every $A\in \pi$ *there exists* a $B\in\pi'$ such that $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: Thank you, with that hint i was able to solve that question.